# Как сохранять в БД сразу 2 картинки?

Tags: html, mysql, django

Создаю магазин на Django, хочу загружать много фотографий в карточку товара, пока код такой:
models.py

```html
class Item(models.Model):
    item_title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=200)
    item_description = models.TextField('Описание')
    item_size = models.CharField('Размер', max_length=10)
    item_price = models.IntegerField('Цена')
    item_pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Дата публицкации')
    item_image = models.ImageField('Картинка', upload_to="images", null=True, blank=True,)
```

Есть варианты как подгрузить не одну картинку?

Comment: Использовать [отношения](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: `ForeignKey` + `Inline`